# How to create a list from user input in python then output list details

Tags: python-3.x

Pseudo-Code

```
def main():
  create an empty list
  value = getInput()
  while value isnt zero:
    add value to the list
    value = getInput()
  printOutput(list)

def getInput():
  prompt the user for a value
  make sure that the value is an int (convert to int)
  return the number

def printOutput(list):
  print out the number of input values
  print out the individual input values
  print out the sum of the input values
```

Comment: Since you've been able to formulate the pseudo-code already, what is it you're actually having trouble with?

Comment: sorry, this is what was given within the assignment description. I tried to translate into python code however it returns errors.

Comment: def main():
    num = []
    value = getInput()
    while value != 0:
        num.append(value)
        value = getInput()
    print()
    printOutput(list)

def getInput():
    inp = input('Please enter a positive integer value (zero to end): ')
    inp = int(inp)
    return inp

def printOutput(list):
    print(num, 'values were entered.')
    print('The values are' ,num)
    print('The sum of the values is' ,sum(num))

main()

Comment: Edit the question with your actual code and the full error tracebacks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you define and call `printOutput`, you name the argument `list`. However, in both `main()` and `printOutput`, the variable being used is actually named `num`. What happens is this:

1. `main` calls `printOutput(list)`, passing it the built-in `list`:
2. `printOutput` receives that argument and assigns it to the local name `list`; and
3. The first line of `printOutput` tries to use `num`, which is not in scope, causing `NameError`.

You should edit the call and definition of `printOutput` to use `num` not `list` (indeed, you should never name variables that shadow built-ins like `list`, `int`, etc.). I suspect he argument is called `list` in the pseudo code to show the type of object the function should expect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
def getInput():
 try:
  value=int(input("Enter a value: "))
 except ValueError:
     value=int(input("You must enter a number:  "))
 return value


def printOutput(lis):
    print(len(lis))
    print(lis)
    print(sum(lis))

def main():
 list_1=[]
 value=getInput()
 while value!=0:
     list_1+=[value]
     value=getInput()
 printOutput(list_1)

main()
```